# how do you use RunSavedImportExport from a macro

Tags: macros, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have yet to figure out all the 'musts' for getting this gem of a macro step to even show up in my macro step drop down.  does anyone know what you have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show all actions - you should then be able to see the command to add it

[image]